# How to set initial ratingbar progress with custom drawables

Tags: android

I have my rating bar

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="10"
    style="@style/myRatingBar"
/>
```

Here is my style `myRatingBar`

```
<style name="myRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_star_full</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/custom_star_empty</item>
</style>
```

In my code I declare the number of full stars to assign the rating bar

```
int currentRating = 6;
mRatingbar.setRating(currentRating);
```

However, all my custom stars appear to be full.

I just wanted 6 of them to be full.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: See my answer bro.

Comment: Rating bar.setRating() never used the int value. You have to use only floatvalue so you need to parse int value to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<style name="webinarRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar_myfeedback</item>
    <item name="android:stepSize">1</item>
    <item name="android:numStars">6</item>
</style>
```

Now, For rating_bar_my_feedback.xml create a file inside drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

// image of your unfill star
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/unfill_star" />

// image of your fill star
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/fill_star" />
```